# difficulty with the creation of the external table

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

i have a strange problem with the creation of the external table.

I have an external table "X" under the user X. If i try to create another External Table by doing the copy and paste of sql code, i have this error when i do 
SELECT * FROM x

> ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
>   ORA-29400: data cartridge error
>   KUP-04040: file  CFO_PC.csv in EPM_SERVICE_DATA not found
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.ORACLE_LOADER", line 19

the EPM_SERVICE_DATA is the directory where is the file CFO_PC.csv

My user have the grand read and write on this directory.

have you no idea what the problem is?

Sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same file?  CFO_PC.csv   Then it should be locked by the original external table.

Copy it,  and create a new external table using the copy (make sure that Operating System write/read privileges are correct for the Oracle Database group.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved, i have copied the sql code from sql developer and it added the code that, it even plays.

LOCATION ( 'CFO_PC.csv' ) is correct 
LOCATION ( EPM_SERVICE_DATA: 'CFO_PC.csv' ) not correct